# Spring mail integration annotation

Tags: spring, email, annotations

I have found the xml config for an email poller in Spring and wanted to know what will the java annotation equivalent be for:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

        <int:channel id="receiveChannel" />
        <!-- replace 'userid and 'password' wit the real values -->
        <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
                            store-uri="pop3://username:password@pop.gmail.com/INBOX"
                                    channel="receiveChannel"
                                    should-delete-messages="false"
                                    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
                        <!-- Will poll every 20 seconds -->
                        <int:poller fixed-rate="20000"/>

        </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
                <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.pop3.port">995</prop>
                <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</prop>
        </util:properties>
</beans>
```